# Match LaTeX reserved characters with regex

Tags: python, regex, latex

I have an HTML to LaTeX parser tailored to what it's supposed to do (convert snippets of HTML into snippets of LaTeX), but there is a little issue with filling in variables. The issue is that variables **should** be allowed to contain the LaTeX reserved characters (namely `# $ % ^ & _ { } ~ \`). These need to be escaped so that they won't kill our LaTeX renderer.

The program that handles the conversion and everything is written in Python, so I tried to find a nice solution. My first idea was to simply do a `.replace()`, but replace doesn't allow you to match only if the first is not a `\`. My second attempt was a regex, but I failed miserably at that.

The regex I came up with is `([^\][#\$%\^&_\{\}~\\])`. I hoped that this would match any of the reserved characters, but only if it didn't have a `\` in front. Unfortunately, this matches ever single character in my input text. I've also tried different variations on this regex, but I can't get it to work. The variations mainly consisted of removing/adding slashes in the second part of the regex.

Can anyone help with this regex?

**EDIT** Whoops, I seem to have included the slashes as well. Shows how awake I was when I posted this :) They shouldn't be escaped in my case, but it's relatively easy to remove them from the regexes in the answers. Thanks all!

Comment: You want to match one backslash, but not two, right? What about three? Do you still want to match the last backslash, even though it has another one in front of it?

Comment: Beware that there’s no such thing as “reserved characters” in TeX. The list you’ve posted is an arbitrary convention that can be redefined at any point (also multiple times) in a document. There is no way to replace general special characters in LaTeX without parsing the document. Don’t let that detract you though, since for your purpose the characters you mentioned are probably fine.

Comment: For our purposes there will be only a non-escaped or an escaped version. We are creating a (very) limited subset of LaTeX from HTML. And that's also why this list should work good enough for us. I would even go as far as to say that all I really **need** to escape right now is the underscore, but it's better to be on the safe side :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[^\]` is a character class for anything not a `\`, that is why it is matching everything.  You want a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
((?<!\)[#\$%\^&_\{\}~\\])
```

`(?<!...)` will match whatever follows it as long as `...` is not in front of it.  You can check this out at the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Note that this does not consider escaped backslashes. I.e. the `#` in `\\#` should actually be matched, but it won't be with this pattern.

Comment: @m.buettner Unfortunately, there's no way to check with regexes whether a preceding backslash is escaped or not, as Python only allows fixed-length strings in lookarounds.

Comment: @Michelle not in a straightforward way, no, but there are some tricks to get this done.

Comment: This seems to work almost perfectly, but I seem to have made a slight error in my original question. Backslashes shouldn't be escaped, but that's easily fixed by removing the last to backslashes from the regexp.

This does seem to be the nicest solution, thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to edit my previous comment... In the end I settled on using the following regexp, which works when using re.sub: ((?<!\\)[#\$%\^&_\{\}~])

Comment: @Xudonax I edited the answer to not have the escaped backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `([^\][#\$%\^&_\{\}~\\])` is matching anything that isn't found between the first `[` and the last `]`, so it should be matching everything except for what you want it to.

Moving around the parenthesis should fix your original regex `([^\\])[#\$%\^&_\{\}~\\]`.

I would try using regex [lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which won't match the character preceding what you want to escape. I'm not a regex expert so perhaps there is a better pattern, but this should work `(?<!\\)[#\$%\^&_\{\}~\\]`.

Comment: This doesn't take care of escaped backslashes either (see my comment on SethMMorton's answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to find special characters that aren't escaped, without eliminating special chars preceded by escaped backslashes (e.g. you do want to match the last backslash in `abc\\\def`), try this:

```
(?<!\\)(\\\\)*[#\$%\^&_\{\}~\\]
```

This will match any of your special characters preceded by an even number (this includes 0) of backslashes. It says the character can be preceded by any number of pairs of backslashes, with a negative lookbehind to say those backslashes can't be preceded by another backslash.

The match will include the backslashes, but if you stick another in front of all of them, it'll achieve the same effect of escaping the special char, anyway.

Comment: This unfortunately gives only empty results when I run it through `re.findall`. When I slightly modify it to `(?<!\\)(\\\\)*([#\$%\^&_\{\}~\\])` it does match, but it also includes double backslashes. As do all others, unfortunately.